# App doesn't open in emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When I run `ionic serve` the app opens in browser as normal and it works. When I do `ionic emulate android` to run the app on an Android Emulator on Windows, I get the following followed by the never ending dots (...).

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see any devices listed when you run `adb devices` on CMD'.

If not then it means you have not created any Device in Android Studio. Head over to Android Studio, Create Device and try again.